# Using XSL to show inner XML pretty printed

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, pretty-print

I have an XML file with an XML string inside one of its elements:

```
<Container>
<Object>
    <Metadata>
        <Fields>
            <Field Label="Contents">
                <Value>&lt;Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns:cur="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:codelist:CurrencyCode:1:0" xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:SpecializedDatatypes:1:0" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;   &lt;cbc:UBLVersionID xmlns=""&gt;2.1&lt;/cbc:UBLVersionID&gt;   &lt;cbc:CustomizationID xmlns=""&gt;urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol4a:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.difi.no:ehf:faktura:ver2.0&lt;/cbc:CustomizationID&gt;   &lt;cbc:ProfileID xmlns=""&gt;urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii04:ver2.0&lt;/cbc:ProfileID&gt;   &lt;cbc:ID xmlns=""&gt;821576&lt;/cbc:ID&gt;   &lt;cbc:IssueDate xmlns=""&gt;2018-04-30&lt;/cbc:IssueDate&gt;   &lt;cbc:InvoiceTypeCode xmlns="" listAgencyID="6" listID="UNCL1001"&gt;380&lt;/cbc:InvoiceTypeCode&gt;   &lt;cbc:TaxPointDate xmlns=""&gt;2018-04-30&lt;/cbc:TaxPointDate&gt;   &lt;cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode xmlns="" listAgencyID="6" listID="ISO4217"&gt;NOK&lt;/cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode&gt;   &lt;cbc:AccountingCost xmlns=""&gt;2007&lt;/cbc:AccountingCost&gt;   &lt;cac:ContractDocumentReference xmlns=""&gt;     &lt;cbc:ID&gt;2007&lt;/cbc:ID&gt;   &lt;/cac:ContractDocumentReference&gt;   &lt;/Invoice&gt;</Value>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
    </Metadata>
</Object>
```

I use an XSLT to produce a valid XML from that string:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="/Container/Object/Metadata/Fields/Field[@Label='Contents']/Value" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns:cur="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:codelist:CurrencyCode:1:0" xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:SpecializedDatatypes:1:0" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   <cbc:UBLVersionID xmlns="">2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>   <cbc:CustomizationID xmlns="">urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol4a:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.difi.no:ehf:faktura:ver2.0</cbc:CustomizationID>   <cbc:ProfileID xmlns="">urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii04:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>   <cbc:ID xmlns="">821576</cbc:ID>   <cbc:IssueDate xmlns="">2018-04-30</cbc:IssueDate>   <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode xmlns="" listAgencyID="6" listID="UNCL1001">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>   <cbc:TaxPointDate xmlns="">2018-04-30</cbc:TaxPointDate>   <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode xmlns="" listAgencyID="6" listID="ISO4217">NOK</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>   <cbc:AccountingCost xmlns="">2007</cbc:AccountingCost>   <cac:ContractDocumentReference xmlns="">     <cbc:ID>2007</cbc:ID>   </cac:ContractDocumentReference>   </Invoice>
```

But since this is in fact still only a string the result is not pretty printed. Is there any way I can get the inner XML and have it formatted as an XML file in one operation? I need an XSLT 2.0 solution for Saxon parser.

Comment: The bottom XML is valid. The root element is Invoice.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Saxon 9.8 you can use XSLT 3 and the `parse-xml` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-parse-xml:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="parse-xml(/Container/Object/Metadata/Fields/Field[@Label='Contents']/Value)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQc.

For earlier versions of Saxon you would need a commercial edition like PE or EE and make use of an extension function like http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/functions/saxon/parse.html in a similar way.

When I run Saxon 9.6.0.9 EE from the command line against your input sample (with a closing end tag added to make it well formed) the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
         xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
         xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"
         xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
         xmlns:cur="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:codelist:CurrencyCode:1:0"
         xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:SpecializedDatatypes:1:0"
         xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
         xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <cbc:UBLVersionID xmlns="">2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
   <cbc:CustomizationID xmlns="">urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol4a:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.difi.no:ehf:faktura:ver2.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
   <cbc:ProfileID xmlns="">urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii04:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
   <cbc:ID xmlns="">821576</cbc:ID>
   <cbc:IssueDate xmlns="">2018-04-30</cbc:IssueDate>
   <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode xmlns="" listAgencyID="6" listID="UNCL1001">380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
   <cbc:TaxPointDate xmlns="">2018-04-30</cbc:TaxPointDate>
   <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode xmlns="" listAgencyID="6" listID="ISO4217">NOK</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
   <cbc:AccountingCost xmlns="">2007</cbc:AccountingCost>
   <cac:ContractDocumentReference xmlns="">
      <cbc:ID>2007</cbc:ID>
   </cac:ContractDocumentReference>
</Invoice>
```

so the output is indented.

Comment: Unfortunately the Saxon library we are using is v. 9.6.0.4. It will allow me to use your XSLT, but the result is still just a long string.

Comment: That would be 9.6.0.4 HE :(

Comment: I would 9.6 HE expect to give an error. I don't see a way of solving that with 9.6 HE other than upgrading to 9.8 HE or with 9.6 to run two transformations where the first outputs and serializes the element as you do and the second then consumes and outputs that result indented.